# Applying a mask to filter a Mat object in OpenCV for Java

Tags: java, opencv

I'm trying to apply a mask to a photo:

```
Mat img = Highgui.imread( "/path/to/my/image.png" );

Mat mask = new Mat( new Size( img.cols(), img.rows() ), CvType.CV_8UC1 );
mask.setTo( new Scalar( 0.0 ) );

// Rect r = ...;
Core.ellipse( mask, new Point( r.x + ( r.width / 2 ), r.y + ( r.height / 2 ) ), new Size( r.width / 2, ( r.height ) / 2 ), 0.0, 0.0, 360.0, new Scalar( 255.0 ), 5 );

// Mat res = ...;
img.copyTo( res, mask );
```

But I always end up with res containing exactly the same image as img...

Comment: Did you check the mask (does it contain 0 values at the borders)? As a different check, you can try: `Mat res = img.mul(mask);`

Comment: I'm new to OpenCV and image processing... Shouldn't the mask.setTo( new Scalar( 0.0 ) ) do that?

Comment: Yes it does! But maybe your ellipse drawing just draws an ellipse too big, etc. So save the mask to a file and have a look at it :).

Comment: I saved the image and checked it: the ellipse hits the border only at the bottom - would that be a prob?

Comment: No, if there are pixels in the mask that are truly 0 they should not be affected in the copyTo operation. Did you try my alternative method res = img.mul(mask)?

Comment: In the end I managed to achieve what I wanted by using Mat.setTo( Scalar, Mat ) but I would still be curious to understand why it didn't work the other way...

Comment: FWIW, I created an ellipse mask using your code sample (updated for OpenCV 3.x), and it was working for me (I saw a black screen with a ring of the original image).

Answer (score 6):

Image example:

[image]

### 1. Create mask with the size of the source image:

```
Mat mask = new Mat(src.rows(), src.cols(), CvType.CV_8U, Scalar.all(0));
```

### 2. Draw in the mask Mat (set thickness to -1 to fill in the shape):

```
Imgproc.ellipse( mask,
                new Point( src.rows() / 2, src.cols() / 2 ),
                new Size( src.rows() / 3, src.cols() / 5 ),
                70.0,
                0.0,
                360.0,
                new Scalar( 255, 255, 255 ),
                -1,
                8,
                0 );
```

[image]

### 3. Apply the mask:

```
Mat cropped = new Mat();
src.copyTo( cropped, mask );
```

[image]